# TabLayout click stutters fragment transition, swipe doesn't

Tags: android

*While clicking* on Tabs on a TabLayout Pagerview (to switch Fragments) animation stutters during its transition, yet doesn't *when swiped*.

Any ideas why?

Suggestions on fixes?

Tried adding an animation duration to Pager.  Had no effect.

```
mPager.animate().translationX(0f).setDuration(500);
```

Comment: Use method tracing or `systrace` to determine where you are spending time on the main application thread.

Comment: Already tried finding an obvious culprit using [Traceview](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/traceview-walkthru.html) but nothing jumped out.  Especially considering swipe action logically does same thing, but without graphical stutter.  Any tips on using Traceview to investigate graphics performance issues?

Comment: Perhaps you are a lot more sensitive to jank than I am, but anything rising to the level of a visible stutter would take ~100ms or more for me. If your swipe-versus-tab difference is reliable, I would expect that difference to be visible when comparing traces from each. Beyond that, I don't have much advice, since we don't have a [mcve] to work off of.

Comment: After narrowing down issue: was Google API (FusedLocationAPI) Connect()  call on Fragment onResume causing a slight hang, even though it's supposed to return immediately.  Moved all location services calls out to Activity onResume/onPause (where it should have been) and all is smooth.  Thanks for feedback.

Comment: While that method will return "immediately", that should involve IPC, so there's a guarantee of a little bit of overhead, and perhaps more depending upon what Play Services is up to at that moment. I cannot explain why there would be a difference between tabs versus swipes if that was the culprit, though. But, I'm glad that you have it smoothed out!